# SendGrid API for .net core does not send emails

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, .net-core, sendgrid

I'm trying to implement sendgrid's .NET CORE API following the guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#debug

But I can't send any emails.

```
    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
    }

    public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
    {
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("myemail@email.it", Options.SendGridUser),
            Subject = subject,
            PlainTextContent = message,
            HtmlContent = message
        };
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

        // Disable click tracking.
        // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
        msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);
        return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
```

The code does not go into error but does not send emails.
Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: If you are using the free SendGrid plan, be aware that certain email providers may block requests from the Azure IPs that send out those emails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I'm using a free plan, are outlook and gmail among those that give problems? because I tried both an office365 mailbox and a gmail. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks good to me. I would verify that your API key is correct. Can you share the code that is actually invoking this method? Exclude the API for security reasons obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using the Identity Controrrel Register, I cannot agree with the code in full because I exceed the length of the comment.

Comment: `public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        {
            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Conferma la tua email",
                $"Conferma il tuo account < a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'> facendo clic qui </a>.");
        }
    }
    return Page();
}`

Comment: Thanks, did you place a breakpoint on this method to see if its even being hit?